# Xamarin.Forms - Android - Change three dots or ellipsis icon in ContentPage.ToolbarItems

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have used the <ContentPage.ToolbarItems> in my code ti display a menu on the top right of the app. My app is only targeting Android at the moment even though it's written in Xamarin.Forms.

I am struggling to change the three dots icon. Any idea how I can achieve that either using Custom Renderer, Effects or styles.xml?

I have seen answers on this overflow but they are all referring to native android and I am struggling to understand how I can do it on Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: When you are working with Xamarin forms it is suggested to minimize use of custom renderer, in your case to fullfil your requirement u need to create a custom view and place the components of your own choice, u don't had to do customer rendering

Comment: @RonakShethia Yes I understand but my requirement is to use either CustomRenderer, Effects or inside styles.xml. Using a custom view is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `style.xml` to achieve that .No mattter in forms or native , this will work .

Add `item` inside `MainTheme.Base` :

```
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>
```

Then adding `style` inside `resourses` :

```
<style name="OverflowButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow">
  <item name="android:src">@drawable/circle</item> //here set the wanted icon
</style>
```

The full `style.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>

  <style name="OverflowButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/circle</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: @AmirNo-Family Share your `style.xml` here , I will check that .